# Python - CSV Reading with dictionary

Tags: python, csv

So,

I am using Python 3.4.2 and I have this code:

```
import csv
import random

filename = input("Please enter the name of your file: ")

# Open file and read rows 0 and 1 into dictionary.
capital_of = dict(csv.reader(open(filename)))

# Randomly select a country from the dictionary
choice = random.choice(capital_of.keys())

# The correct capital corresponds to the dictionary entry for the country
answer = capital_of[choice]

# Take a guess from the user
guess = input("What is the capital of %s? " % choice)

# If it's right, let the user know
if guess == answer:
  print("Right-o!")
# Otherwise, do what you want to do.
```

This code was given to me as a solution on a previous question but upon entering the name of my CSV file, I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing
```

Does anybody know a fix for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
choice = random.choice(list(capital_of.keys()))
```